# Retrofit Execute Method Network Error on Main Thread

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, networkonmainthread

I have the following code in my fragment, specifically in my `onViewCreated`:

```
searchResponse = searchCall.execute()

if (!searchResponse.isSuccessful || searchResponse.body()!!.results!!.isEmpty()) {
    // code
} else {
    getResponse = getCall.execute()
    // more code

    if (!getResponse.isSuccessful || getResponse.body()!!.extendedIngredients!!.isEmpty()) {
        // more code
    } else {
       convertResponse = convertCall.execute()
       // more code
    }
}
```

Obviously not the entire code, but it's a very simplified version of the basic structure for that block of code. Basically, I'm running three API calls via retrofit and I need them to run one at a time since the `getResponse` API request depends on the data I get from `searchResponse` and `convertResponse` API request depends on the data I get from `getResponse`. This is why I didn't use Retrofit's `enqueue` because that runs the API calls asynchronously, whereas I'm trying to run them synchronously. How do I get `execute` method to work? Righ now I'm getting an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` error.

Comment: Why don't you still run `searchResponse` asynchronously and then check the result in the main thread and if you need to call `getResponse` you just run another async task and again check the result in the main thread and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [RXJava + Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2) to chain your API calls.

Although the most straightforward solution would just be to execute all of your code on another thread. There are numerous ways to achieve this, using Kotlin Coroutines is an option in Android.

If you're executing the code in a fragment, activity etc:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

    searchResponse = searchCall.execute()

    ...

}
```